# Как переделать скрипт чтоб картинки доставались когда компьютер не подключен к сети?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть приложение которое загружает картинки в локальное хранилище . как изменить скрипт таким образом чтоб картинки он доставал когда компютер не подключен к сети ?

сам скрипт :

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
if (images.length > 0) {
  // в Storage
  var dataArray = [];
  for (var i = 0, itemsLength = images.length; i < itemsLength; i++) {
    dataArray.push({
      img: getBase64Image(images[i]),
      id: images[i].id || ''
    });
  }
  localStorage.setItem("imagesData", JSON.stringify(dataArray));

  //из Storage
  var storageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('imagesData'));
  if (Array.isArray(storageArray)) {
    storageArray.map(function(dataImage) {
      var element = document.getElementById(dataImage.id);
      if (element) {
        element.src = "data:image/png;base64," + dataImage.img;
      }
    });
  }
}

function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

```html
<img id="bannerImg" class="image" crossOrigin="*" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Proton-K-Zarya.jpg/800px-Proton-K-Zarya.jpg" />
<img id="tableBanner" class="image" crossOrigin="*" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Richard_of_Shrewsbury%2C_1._Duke_of_York.jpg?download" />
```

Вот код на фидле : http://jsfiddle.net/zolotnitskiy/4ra8nhk4/4/

Comment: Может вы перестанете коверкать `javaskript`?

Comment: @Visman, о чём вы ?

Comment: `javascript` :D   Владимир Мартьянов, поправил тег.

Comment: @Visman надо бы некорректный удалить вообще, не знаю как :-/

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, аналогично.

Comment: @Visman, кажется, неиспользуемые теги со временем сами удаляются.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а если неиспользуемый тег имеет/является синонимом?

Comment: @Visman, тогда, наверное, не должен... А зачем его синонимом сделали?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не про этот тег спрашивал, а про apache22 и apache2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете написать небольшой объект, который мониторит наличие сети. То есть, например, каждые ~30 секунд шлет очень простенький AJAX на сервер или пытается скачать однопиксельную GIF'ку. Если операция не удалась, можно попробовать повторить запрос. Если и это не удалось, то можно сказать, что интернет в данный момент не активен и подгрузить фотографии.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать оффлайн-приложение при помощи соответствующего файла манифеста и не забивать localStorage.

[Статья на хабре.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/71939/)

Comment: @Valeriy1996, и что?

Comment: это приложение всего для одног устройства, которое большенство времени будет , без инета, это что-то типа офланового каталога. Думаете через манифест всё таки лучше будет чем через хранилище?

Comment: Просто спрашиваю , пытаюсь определить что , лучше подходит)

Comment: Просто не знаю, зачем делать руками то, что можно свалить на браузер? Но так, проверяй.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    // your code 
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что где-то оно не очень-то и работает...

Comment: Browser Support :
Chrome 14+;
Iexplorer YES;
FireFox 3.5+;
Safari 5.0.4+
opera YES

Comment: Третья сноска про FF40- (это текущая стабильная версия! хотя в более новой уже исправили): Desktop Firefox responds to the status of its "Work Offline" mode. If not in that mode, navigator.onLine is always true, regardless of the actual network connectivity status.